# Checking if subgraph fulfill condition as a whole

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I find it hard to explain, so consider the following picture
[image]

I'm trying to select all products that fulfill the warehouse requirements

In this example I need to select all products that have a maximum size of 5 AND maximum weight of 10.

To simplify, I only have MAX (no MIN or EQ) constraints, so the operator can be hardcoded.

I've tried to group the requirement subgraph using COLLECT and using the ALL operator, but failed.

### Query to create the graph

```
CREATE
  // NODES
  (warehouse:WAREHOUSE{name:'My Warehouse'}),
  (smallProduct:PRODUCT{name:'Small Product'}),
  (largeProduct:PRODUCT{name:'Large Product'}),
  // RELATIONSHIPS
  (size:CONSTRAINT{name:'Size'}),
  (weight:CONSTRAINT{name:'Weight'}),
  (warehouse)-[:LIMIT{value:5}]->(size),
  (warehouse)-[:LIMIT{value:5}]->(weight),
  (smallProduct)-[:AMOUNT{value:3}]->(size),
  (smallProduct)-[:AMOUNT{value:2}]->(weight),
  (largeProduct)-[:AMOUNT{value:10}]->(size),
  (largeProduct)-[:AMOUNT{value:4}]->(weight)
```

---

## UPDATE

The following query apparently solves the problem:

```
MATCH  (warehouse:WAREHOUSE)
MATCH rel = ((warehouse)-[limit:LIMIT]->(constraint:CONSTRAINT)<-[amount:AMOUNT]-(product:PRODUCT))
WITH warehouse, product, collect(relationships(rel)) as paths
WHERE all( p in paths WHERE p[0].value > p[1].value )
return product
```

I am wondering if there is a better solution.

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far (query or code) and what are the issues you are facing?

Comment: @Raj I've updated the post with more information